# If $X\sim F_1,Y\sim F_2$, what conditions on $F_1,F_2$ are needed s.t. we can construct $Y=E(X|\mathscr{G})$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have distributions $F_1 $ and $F_2$. Under what conditions on $F_1,F_2$ is it possible to construct random variables $X\sim F_1,Y\sim F_2$ such that $Y=E(X|\mathscr{G})$, that is, $Y$ is the conditional expectation of $X$ with respect to some $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{G}$?

Comment: Is it necessary that $Z$ is independent of $Y$, rather than just uncorrelated?

For example, suppose $Y$ is Bernoulli with p=0.5. Define $X$ as follows: if $Y=0$, $X=0$. If $Y=1$, $X=0$ with probability 1/2 and $X=2$ with probability 1/2. I believe this satisfies $Y=E(X|\mathscr{G})$, but I don't think it's true that $X=Y+Z$ for independent $Y,Z$, and thus I'm not sure the convolution formula holds.

Comment: Of course, dunno what I was thinking. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: The question was asked and answered in [this Math Overflow thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221034/if-x%E2%88%BCf-1-y%E2%88%BCf-2-under-what-conditions-on-f-1-f-2-can-we-construct-y-e).